# text field lost focus still editable?

Tags: javascript, focus, internet-explorer-6

I have to move focus to parent frame using JAVASCRIPT:focus().

The thing is that **text field lost focus still got cursor in it and editable**.

Is there any way to fix this?

※ the issue occurs under IE6. (IE8 works great as I intended.)

Here's source,

//--- 1.html

```
<iframe src="2.html"></iframe>
<form name="frmMain">
    <input type="button" name="btnConfirm" value="CONFIRM" />
</form>
```

//--- 2.html

```
<head>
    <script language="javascript">
        function test() {
            keynum = event.keyCode;
            if (keynum == 9 || keynum == 13)
                parent.frmMain.btnConfirm.focus();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" onKeyDown="test()" />
    <input type="text" value="dummy" />
```

Comment: First off, you shouldn't support IE6 (google IE6 countdown), but anyway, `.blur()` to the text field (which btw doesn't exist in your code, as there's only a button) might help)

Comment: @JCOC611 - whether developers write code to support a particular browser or not is a business decision that should be put to whoever makes such decisions. Given the cost of supporting IE 6 in this instance was a few minutes here, it would likely only take one happy customer to make it worthwhile.

Comment: @RobG: Yes, it is solely the OP's decision, and I won't argue with that. However, I think that IE6 shouldn't be kept alive...that's just me... kimchoky: I'm glad :) I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding `.blur()` to the input before the setting the new `.focus()`